# Getting select item from three different spinners using a button to show simple fragment

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am using three spinners so that the user can choose: origin, destiny and time. Depending of 3 items chosen from the spinners i want to show a fragment. I have created the spinners and the button populated the spinner using an array-list.

Example:

```
final Spinner Time = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.time, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Time.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

The problem is that i am not being able to get the items selected by the user so that i can show the fragment.

I have tried to use this:

```
            Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                   Origin.getSelectedItem();
                   Destiny.getSelectedItem();
                   Time.getSelectedItem();

                   Origin.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   Destiny.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   Time.getSelectedItem().toString();


if (Origin.getSelectedItem()=="Lisbon" && Destiny.getSelectedItem()=="Ponta Delgada" && Time.getSelectedItem()=="7:00–8:00") {
    FragmentTwo firstFragment = new FragmentTwo();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.main, firstFragment)
            .commit();      
                   }
    }});                       
}
```

Comment: Your equivalencies are off. String == String isn't valid, it needs to be String.equals(String)

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem! :)